# There's default user "centos" after create instance VM in centos 8

Tags: centos, ssh, users

I'm new using CentOS for new experience, after i tried ubuntu.
I was created instance CentOS 8.2 and there's user show "centos" and my private user after i list directory in home.

Is the default user CentOS is a normal? or It was come from my cloud provider? If so, how do i login with "centos" from SSH?

I'm a root

[image]

Comment: Did you check if the user `centos` has a password and is not locked? This can be checked with `passwd`

Comment: @Panki 
```[inhospital21@in-hospital ~]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep centos
centos:x:1000:1000:Cloud User:/home/centos:/bin/bash```

What that means?

Comment: `man 5 passwd` has the answer

Comment: @Panki thank you, i just changed ```centos``` password with ```passwd``` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `centos` user is present on all CentOS cloud images. It doesn't have password set (if it had password it would mean all CentOS cloud instances share the same password), you should be able to SSH to it using your SSH key (usually you provide your SSH key when creating the instance, but this can be different with your cloud provider).

If you don't want to use this account you can remove it or you can set password for the user using `passwd`.